# Need to keep ESTA active for Nexus card?

Tags: usa, canada, esta, nexus

I have a Nexus card as a Canadian PR. Meanwhile my ESTA for entering the US is about the expire. Does Nexus require me to always keep a valid ESTA?

(I seem to remember a Nexus agent once told me so, but I could not find anything when searching the web.  I have no need to enter the US these days...)

Comment: AFAIK you need a valid ESTA to enter the US but not to keep the membership in general. I’ll try to find some authoritative reference but no luck yet.

Comment: thank you for your comment! that would make sense to me. it's surprising this isn't discussed in any easy-to-find reference...